# How to load all jquery tabs by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery dynamic tabs for creating/editing contents.While creating new contents, its working fine.But when we edit the same content, we need to load all tabs contents to be loaded by default so that it will be available at the time of persisting.

Comment: where you keep the content (textarea, inputs, ...)?. containing the other tabs (divs, iframe ,..), saw events change?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question: [How to load all jQuery ui tabs by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724353/preload-jquery-ui-tabs-in-the-background/1725441#1725441)